# Getting current active page in Django's Flatpages

Tags: django

I'm using flatpages to add my content.

I was wondering if there was a way to get the active page so I can style it properly on my navigational bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flatpages app uses `RequestContext`, which means that details from the request are pushed up through the middleware. You can access these request variables in templates if the `request` template context processor is enabled. Once you enable this, then all your templates will have access to the request, and from there you can get the current requested URL.

So,

1. Enable the `django.core.context_processors.request` template context processor (its not enabled by default). You need to make sure you don't disable the default context processors, so add this to your `settings.py`:

   ```
   from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as TCP

   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = TCP + (
       'django.core.context_processors.request',
   )
   ```
2. In your template, use [`{{ request.get_full_path }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) or [`{{ request.path }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your using django flat pages, then you will already have the URL's defined.

```
EG:  url(r'^license/$', 'flatpage', {'url': '/license/'}, name='license'),
```

Using request.path_info should get you the current page. Is that what you where looking for is there of is it something else ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{ flatpage.url }}" {% if flatpage.url == request.path %}class="active-page"{% endif %}>{{ flatpage.title }}</a>
```

If you have issues with your request context, you can check Burhan Khalid's answer.